# GWT Mobile/Touch screen device - Auto hide PopupPanel with glass enabled triggers touch/click on underlying widgets when tapping on the glass

Tags: mobile, gwt, popup, touch

I am trying to use GWT PopupPanel (or DialogBox) with glass and autohide enabled to create a context actions menu on mobile devices, but I have an issue when the user whats to close the actions menu popup (by tapping on the glass of the popup, outside the content to trigger autohide): the underlying widgets ("beneath" the glass) also receive the tap event when the popup is closed. For example, if there is a button at that position that opens a new view/window, the button is clicked and executes his click handler.

My code:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Button button = new Button("Test");
    button.addClickHandler(cl -> {
        
        Label lb = new Label("This is the content");
        lb.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("#fff");
        lb.setSize("200px", "80px");

        
        DialogBox pop = new DialogBox();
        pop.setAutoHideEnabled(true);
        pop.setGlassEnabled(true);
        pop.setWidget(lb);
        pop.center();
                    
    });
    
    Button buttonBehindGlass = new Button("Test over");
    buttonBehindGlass.addClickHandler(cl -> {           
        Window.alert("Action 2");           
    }); 
    
    RootPanel.get().add(button);
    RootPanel.get().add(buttonBehindGlass);
}
```

In this example, if you open the popup, then click/tap outside the content, on the glass, over the "buttonBehindGlass" widget, you will notice that the popup closes and "buttonBehindGlass" is clicked, at the same time.

Is there any way to avoid this?

I tested on Android and Chrome dev tools enabled with responsive/touch mode. This issue does not appear on desktop, everything is fine there.

Answer (score 0):

**Create your own DialogBox**, based on the GWT one

```
public class DialogBoxExtended extends DialogBox {

    @Override
    protected void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        super.onPreviewNativeEvent(event);

        // check if the event does not target the popup
        Event nativeEvent = Event.as(event.getNativeEvent());
        if (!eventTargetsPopup(nativeEvent)) {
            // on click, touch end, etc. close the dialog box
            switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
            case Event.ONMOUSEDOWN:
            case Event.ONCLICK:
            case Event.ONTOUCHEND:
                hide();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Does the event target this popup?
     *
     * @param event the native event
     * @return true if the event targets the popup
     */
    private boolean eventTargetsPopup(NativeEvent event) {
        EventTarget target = event.getEventTarget();
        if (Element.is(target)) {
            return getElement().isOrHasChild(Element.as(target));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**disable auto hide** and **use your created DialogBox**

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Button button = new Button("Test");
    button.addClickHandler(cl -> {
        
        Label lb = new Label("This is the content");
        lb.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("#fff");
        lb.setSize("200px", "80px");    
        
        DialogBox pop = new DialogBoxExtended();
        pop.setAutoHideEnabled(false);
        pop.setGlassEnabled(true);
        pop.setWidget(lb);
        pop.center();
                    
    });
    
    Button buttonBehindGlass = new Button("Test over");
    buttonBehindGlass.addClickHandler(cl -> {           
        Window.alert("Action 2");           
    }); 
    
    RootPanel.get().add(button);
    RootPanel.get().add(buttonBehindGlass);
}
```

It now works as expected.

With auto hide enabled the event is processed but left to be consumed by other handlers - that's why the event gets to the underlying button. On desktop it was not a problem because `Event.ONMOUSEUP` was being considered, but on mobile/touch mode the `Event.ONTOUCHEND` is being triggered instead.